# Select evenly distributed points from the 300 unevenly distributed points on the circle

Tags: algorithm

I have 300 points on a circle that are not uniformly distributed, and I want to select some points from them that are as close to uniform distribution as possible.

[image]
I tried the Dijkstra algorithm mentioned in [Selecting evenly distributed points algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227014/selecting-evenly-distributed-points-algorithm.But) can not be well overcome “holes".
The Dijkstra algorithm i used is to consider this problem as a one-dimensional distribution problem, filtered by setting the spacing, but Dijkstra's algorithm will skip points when faced with the limitation of insufficient number of points in some regions, i.e., when I follow 360/49 with the goal of selecting 50 points, I am likely to select only 40 or so, and when I modify the spacing by adding multiple powers, I will appear to jump from 48 points to 300 points in one fell swoop
I have also tried to use K-means clustering, but there is a big gap between the location of the cluster center and the real points, and finding the closest point to the cluster center of mass after clustering will greatly increase the computational effort.
So can I randomly select a point and add the point in the data that is farthest from the one I have already selected. Then keep calculating the distance between each point and my selected point, and keep adding the farthest point until the number of points meet my requirement?

The " evenly distributed points" is this

[image]

For me, this problem wants to be applied to a satellite selection algorithm, a typical satellite selection algorithm (4 satellites) when it needs to be constructed as a uniform tetrahedron, that is, it needs a uniform distribution of three satellites on a circle, an extension of this problem may require more uniformly distributed satellites

Comment: So you have 300 satellites on a circle, and you want to pick 3 that are 120 degrees apart?

Comment: i want to select more than 3,3 is just an example of basic

Comment: I'd start by converting all of the (x,y) positions to angles, using the `atan2` function. Then you have the one dimensional problem to solve.

Comment: sure i try Dijkstra algorithm it is a one dimensional problem,but i fails

Comment: @user3386109 does the one dimensional problem take into account the "wrap around" nature of a circle, in that we also need to take into account the sum of the distances from each end to its nearest point?

Comment: @גלעדברקן You are correct that wrap around must be handled. That can be accomplished by using integer math (i.e. [fixed point math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)) and the modulo operator. Even better is scaling the range (0, 2) to (0, 65536) and using unsigned 16-bit variables. Then the wrap around can be handled implicitly.

Comment: Your difficulty are not angle ranges with too many satellites, but ranges with too few, i.e. where the gaps get too large. You could identify those ranges and definitely include the boundaries of those ranges. Afterwards you can freely add some suitable satellites from the dense regions. You can also decide, whether in this constellation (...1000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000001...) you want to merge the two middle ones from 101, both bordering on a large gap.

Comment: If you have enough satellites to get a nearly optimal solution, you could also (in the case of 3 chosen ones) loop in a fine way over 0°..120° and testing for each value (e.g. 53°), whether adding the nearest with this modulo (e.g. the nearest to 53°, 53°+120°, 53°+240°) gives a good result. The best results found this way can be further optimized then as a second step.

Comment: If you want to choose many satellites over the whole circle, you could also find locally good/optimal solutions with the expected overall density. E.g. solve the problem (with several solution candidates) for quarter circles and then combine the solutions to find the best mix for all four quarters.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the `n` most uniform points among a cloud of `N` points remembers me the *'solid with same area and maximun volume'* (happens to be the sphere).

I'm not a mathematician, so you better ask at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Continuing with my idea, I think that the convex hull of the `n` solution points has the greatest volume of all possible `C{N,n}` combinations.

So, a brute force algorithm may be:

1. Get a combination of `n` points
2. Calculate its convex hull (Delaunay, with tetrahedra)
3. Calculate the volume of this hull (sum of all tetrahedra volumes)
4. Repeat from 1., storing the combination with greatest volume

But... C{300,6} = 962,822,846,700 combinations, which makes this method unfeasible for big `N`.

Another approach is accepting that "uniform" means "balanced in X,Y,Z coordinates". for example, I'm not talking about the euclidean distance but a metric such as:

```
dij = (abs(xi-xj))^k + (abs(yi-yj))^k + (abs(zi-zj))^k
```

where `k` is a factor `k<=1` (k=2 is euclidean lacking the total sqrt)

Given a point `i` you may select the `s` point that makes the above formula to be the greatest value.

Once you have the pair {i,s} search for another pair. But be aware that testing a `j` point must be excluded if it's too close to (i,s) already selected.

This is also brute-force, but now with C{300,2}= 44,850 combinations for each pair.

Finally, if you can arrange the `N` points into a KD-tree or a quadtree, you can tell regions, and extract representatives, and then work only with them.

Answer (score 0):

Now i have a new way to do this problem
Using a genetic algorithm, where the goal is to minimise the sum of the squares of these three values (the primary term can be quadratic, and the quadratic term squared), it is possible to filter out methods that are relatively able to satisfy these three equations